# Android: Get SSID and password of a phone which is a portable wifi hotspot

Tags: android, portability, ssid

I need to find a way to get the SSID of the network that my Android device is shared (My device is being a portable wifi hotspot).

Not the SSID of the network I connected to.

thanks

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to programming. It would be best asked here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually I want to get the information in my APP programmatically.

Comment: Ok, what is your question? There doesn't appear to be one in your post. Also, what have you tried so far? I am pretty sure that the only application that would have access to the password of your hotspot is the one that runs the hotspot itself. It would be rather unsecure for other apps to have access to that info.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, it's just OP didn't express it too clearly. OP wants the SSID and possibly the password of the current hotspot AP of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found that there are some hidden method about getting/setting wifiAP mode in android WifiManager class. In WifiManager class, getWifiApConfiguration could be invoke to get the configuration in which the SSID of wifiAp could be found.

Answer (score 1):

I know OP has already answered his/her own question, but it wasn't too clear for me, so I'll just post my complete solution here for future people that got here:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
Method[] methods = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m: methods) {           
    if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
        WifiConfiguration config = (WifiConfiguration)m.invoke(wifimanager);
        String ssid = config.SSID;
        String bssid = config.BSSID;
        //or other info about the current hotspot, accessible through config
    }
}
```

**Note**: you would need the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```